# Access to variables in same class but different methods in java

Tags: java

i'm new with java and i have some a difficult to access some variables from different methods but in the same class.

my code:

```
class upgradeSim {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException {

        System.out.print("\n[INFO]: Please enter the version you would like to upgarde to: ");
        Scanner inputVer = new Scanner(System.in);
        String uiVersion = inputVer.nextLine();
}

        public static void SendShhCmd() {
            //some code
        }


        public static void StartUpgrade() throws JSchException {    
            String cmd = ("SCP data/mdusr/perforce/automationtools/builds/ui/"+uiVersion);
        }
}
```

the problem is that ***StartUpgrade*** method does not recognized ***uiVersion*** variable.

i tired using "this" and "super" but no luck...

thanks for the help.

Comment: I would start with trying to understand class members ... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html, then you decide if it should be all static or not.

Comment: try to understand the concept of variable-scopes first. There are plenty of articles regarding this topic available.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `uiVersion` as a **static** member of the `upgradeSim` class:

```
class upgradeSim {
    public static String uiVersion;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException {
        System.out.print("\n[INFO]: Please enter the version you would like to upgarde to: ");
        Scanner inputVer = new Scanner(System.in);
        uiVersion = inputVer.nextLine();
    }
    ...

    public static void StartUpgrade() throws JSchException {  
        // Now, 'uiVersion' is accessible  
        String cmd = ("SCP data/mdusr/perforce/automationtools/builds/ui/"+uiVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `startUpgrade()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Make uiVersion a class variable:

```
class upgradeSim {
    public static String uiVersion;

    etc.

}
```

And set the variable in your main method like this:

```
uiVersion = inputVer.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

**uiVersion** varibale is local, only accessible in main method, so you cannot access to it from StartUpgrade method.
Declare the **uiVersion** as a static member of the **UpgradeSim** class

```
class UpgradeSim {
  private static String UI_VERSION; 

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException {

    System.out.print("\n[INFO]: Please enter the version you would like to upgarde to: ");
    Scanner inputVer = new Scanner(System.in);
    UI_VERSION = inputVer.nextLine();
  }

  public static void SendShhCmd() {
        //some code
  }


  public static void StartUpgrade() throws JSchException {    
        String cmd = ("SCP   data/mdusr/perforce/automationtools/builds/ui/"+uiVersion);
     // use UI_VERSION;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call **UI_VERSION** and you found it null?

Answer (score 0):

You  should create a global variable named `uiVersion` like this:

```
  class upgradeSim {

    static String uiVersion ;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException {

    ...
     uiVersion = inputVer.nextLine(); 
     ...
```